# enabling jquery2 in an admin module for prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm using prestashop 1.7.2.0 to write an admin module that adds nested categories and products from a csv file. I understood that `addJQuery()` is deprecated and I'm trying to get jquery code to work. `I get Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

I have created a `displayBackOfficeHeader` hook with the following:

```
public function hookDisplayBackOfficeHeader(){
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'/js/jqShim.min.js');
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'/css/getcontent.css');
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'/js/getcontent.js');
}
```

as you can see I have tried including `jqShim.min.js` and I still got the same error. what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include `$this->context->controller->addJquery();` in first line of your `hookDisplayBackOfficeHeader()` function.

Comment: $this->context->controller->addJquery();